# How can I solve error - "Object is possibly 'null'"?

Tags: angular, typescript, compiler-errors

In my Angular project Typescript code I am getting the error:

```
Object is possibly 'null'
```

on this line:

```
document.querySelector<HTMLElement>('.highlighted').style.backgroundColor = 'white';
```

If I add `?` to above line like this:

```
document.querySelector<HTMLElement>('.highlighted')?.style.backgroundColor = 'white';
```

then I get the following error:

```
The left-hand side of an assignment expression may not be an optional property access.ts(2779)
```

I need help to solve either of these errors.

Comment: Check with an `if` statement like `const elem = document...; if (elem) { ... }`

Comment: Store `document.querySelector<HTMLElement>('.highlighted')` in a variable and check if it is not null using if statement

Comment: And anyway, try to avoid directly accessing and manipulating the DOM in Angular whenever possible (and it's usually possible). It leads to unmaintainable spaghetti code quite fast.

Answer (score 5):

[`document.querySelector()` can return `null`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector#return_value). Assign it to a variable, then use an `if` statement to assert that it is not null before assigning to one of its properties:

```
const element = document.querySelector<HTMLElement>('.highlighted');

if (element) {
  element.style.backgroundColor = 'white';
}
```

Alternatively if you know from the context of your program that this query will not return `null`, you can use a [TypeScript non-null assertion (`!`)](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-0.html#non-null-assertion-operator):

```
document.querySelector<HTMLElement>('.highlighted')!.style.backgroundColor = 'white';
```

Answer (score 1):

Angular v12 has strict type and null checks. For this reason, the '!' comes in handy.
Can use it as such :

[Usage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z51m0.png)

It is good practice to manage with an else condition, assign '!' only when you are sure the object won't be empty.

(Code Context: trying to map the routes with the url containing param-> id)